# How to get the first row with dupes and without using the row_number function?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I am running some SQL on a ubuntu machine, and it looks like the Windows Functions are not available.  I'm trying to get this to run.

```
SELECT date, deb, req
FROM   (SELECT  date, deb, req,
               Row_number() OVER(Partition BY date, deb, req  ORDER BY date, deb, req ) rn
        FROM   fsm) t
WHERE  rn = 1
And data_date >= '01/01/2020'
```

It seems like that doesn't work, so I tested a couple other ideas and couldn't get it running.  I am using MySQL.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only. Which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are running a 5.x version of MySQL, where window functions are not available.

Your query makes little sense, because it has the same columns in the `partition` and `order by` clause of the window function; let me assume that you want one record per `date` and `deb`, that has the smallest `req`.

If so, you can implement the same logic by filtering your dataset with a correlated subquery:

```
select date, deb, req
from fsm f
where date >= '2020-01-01' and f.req = (
    select min(f1.req)
    from fsm f1
    where f1.date = f.date and f1.deb = f.deb
)
```

This is equivalent *as long as* there no duplicate `(date, deb, req)` in the table; in that case, the subquery solution returns all duplicates, while the window functions returns just one of them. If that's a problem, you can still work around this for this particular query with `select distinct` in the outer query.

Notes that the date literal in your original query is malformed; MySQL wants date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`